# App crashes with Runtime exception when reopening within 15-20 seconds

Tags: android, parse-platform

I enabled Local Datastore for my application. Everything is working fine, pinning and unpinning. But whenever I reopen the app (without reinstalling) within ~20 secs I get ANR with the [stacktrace here](http://pastebin.com/teaJesge).

The runtime exception says `enableOfflineStore() called multiple times.`
but I couldnt find any `disableOfflineStore` or `disableLocalDataStore` option.

The command at line `com.example.try_masterdetail.WebsiteListActivity.onCreate(WebsiteListActivity.java:60)` is `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());`
After clicking OK on ANR dialog box and opening again the app works again.

I dont know if it is a bug or I should call something in onStop or somewhere in my Activity's lifecycle. I tried to search but couldnt find anything. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with this is that the Parse.initialize and Parse.enableLocalDatastore should be called in class extending Application and not Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make it clear for you?

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: enableOfflineStore() called multiple times.
   05-09 19:06:30.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):     at           com.parse.OfflineStore.enableOfflineStore(OfflineStore.java:40)
     05-09 19:06:30.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):     at      com.parse.Parse.enableLocalDatastore(Parse.java:161)
     05-09 19:06:30.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):     at

Comment: Yes I read that but I couldnt find any `disableOfflineStore` or `disableLocalDataStore` option.

Comment: i thought it was part of your source code, as it appears to be from the stacktrace. Something in the line 40 of the file OfflineStore.java is making your app crash.

Comment: Yes, seeing this I had filed a bug at Parse.com too. I reckon there should be a disableLocalStore option too.